# Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a simple regular expression to match the same character being repeated more than 10 or so times. So for example, if I have a document littered with horizontal lines:

```
=================================================
```

It will match the line of `=` characters because it is repeated more than 10 times. **Note** that I'd like this to work for *any* character.

Comment: the title of this asnwer is misleading, you should have said 'Regular expression to match any character repeated more than 10 times'

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The regex you need is `/(.)\1{9,}/`.

Test:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $regex = qr/(.)\1{9,}/;
print "NO" if "abcdefghijklmno" =~ $regex;
print "YES" if "------------------------" =~ $regex;
print "YES" if "========================" =~ $regex;
```

Here the `\1` is called a backreference. It references what is captured by the dot  `.` between the brackets `(.)` and then the `{9,}` asks for nine or more of the same character. Thus this matches ten or more of any single character.

Although the above test script is in Perl, this is very standard regex syntax and should work in any language. In some variants you might need to use more backslashes, e.g. Emacs would make you write `\(.\)\1\{9,\}` here.

If a whole string should consist of 10 or more identical characters, add anchors around the pattern:

```
my $regex = qr/^(.)\1{9,}$/;
```

Answer (score 46):

In Python you can use `(.)\1{9,}`

- (.) makes group from one char (any char)
- \1{9,} matches nine or more characters from 1st group

example:

```
txt = """1. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2. bb
3. cccccccccccccccccccc
4. dd
5. eeeeeeeeeeee"""
rx = re.compile(r'(.)\1{9,}')
lines = txt.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    rxx = rx.search(line)
    if rxx:
        print line
```

Output:

```
1. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3. cccccccccccccccccccc
5. eeeeeeeeeeee
```

Comment: if re.search(line): print line (the assignemnt to the rxx variable is not necessary)

Comment: You are right in this simple context. Using variable rxx I can do something like rxx.group(1), rxx.start(1) etc.

Answer (score 7):

`.` matches any character. Used in conjunction with the curly braces already mentioned:

```
$: cat > test
========
============================
oo
ooooooooooooooooooooooo


$: grep -E '(.)\1{10}' test
============================
ooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

Comment: Hi Jeek and @SilentGhost. The two commands `grep -E '([=o])\1{10}' test` and `grep -E '([=o]){10}' test` works fine with your example (note the lack of `\1` in the second command). But the command `grep -E '([=o])\1{10}' <<< '==o==o==o==o==o==o===o==o==='` does not match the line! However the command without `\1` matches the line: `grep -E '([=o]){10}' <<< '==o==o==o==o==o==o===o==o==='`. Please could you explain? Cheers ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
={10,}
```

matches `=` that  is repeated 10 or more times.

Comment: sure that this does not take 10 or more arbitrary characters?

Comment: `perl -e 'print "NO" if "abcdefghijklmno" =~ /.{10,}/;'`

Comment: it was wrong, but it has been edited (to match my answer which got some downvotes, good)

Comment: *Gee, didn't know I had to say explicitly that you can replace the character with anything you want.*

Answer (score 2):

use the {10,} operator:

```
$: cat > testre
============================
==
==============

$: grep -E '={10,}' testre
============================
==============
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [PowerShell to quickly replace words](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/06/06/quickly-replace-words-in-text-file.aspx) or character reptitions. PowerShell is for Windows. Current version is 3.0.

```
$oldfile = "$env:windir\WindowsUpdate.log"

$newfile = "$env:temp\newfile.txt"
$text = (Get-Content -Path $oldfile -ReadCount 0) -join "`n"

$text -replace '/(.)\1{9,}/', ' ' | Set-Content -Path $newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `preg_replace` example:

```
$str = "motttherbb fffaaattther";
$str = preg_replace("/([a-z])\\1/", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Here `[a-z]` hits the character, `()` then allows it to be used with `\\1` backreference which tries to match another same character (note this is targetting 2 consecutive characters already), thus:

> mother father

If you did:

```
$str = preg_replace("/([a-z])\\1{2}/", "", $str);
```

that would be erasing 3 consecutive repeated characters, outputting:

> moherbb her

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more generic powershell example.  In powershell 7, the match is highlighted including the last space (can you highlight in stack?).

```
'a b c d e f ' | select-string '([a-f] ){6,}'

a b c d e f
```