# jQuery checking for spurious entry

Tags: jquery, regex, forms, character

I have a form which the user has to fill in. A couple of fields are required to have a minimum of 50 characters. I need to stop the user from entering i.e. over 50 full stops, or another letter/number. I've managed to trap the entry of multiple full stops but does anyone know of a JavaScript/jQuery regular expression to find maybe 5 or more of any character in sequence?

Many thanks in advance,

Jason

Comment: `jQuery` __and__ `winforms`? WTF?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779477/regex-for-detecting-the-same-character-more-than-five-times

Comment: @pablo sorry, no idea, I search for and clicked "forms"

Comment: @kei thanks that's great for PHP, but I need to regex it client side using Javascript. How would I go about using this expression with Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I managed to figure it out :) `code` myvar.match(/(\S){5,}/g) `code`

Comment: @superjaz1, sorry, haven't noticed that you already solved your problem. Please post your answer and mark it as accepted even if you managed to find it by yourself.

Comment: @Hnatt I tried when I found the solution but it wouldn't let me. First time here sorry. I'll try again

Comment: @Hnatt thanks! I've accepted your answer, yours seems to work better anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.match(/(.)\1{5,}/);
```

This means: match any character, place it in a capturing group 1, and match this group repeating 5 or more times.