# Regex for matching grey colors in hexadecimal notation

Tags: regex

I've an XML file containing (among a lot of other stuff) hexadecimal color codes. I want to inspect all such codes that result in shades of grey. The pattern is

- a hash tag (#) then
- [a-fA-F0-9] repeated exactly 3 or 6 times
- [^a-fA-F0-9]

So it should match #eee, #EEEEEE, #333333 but not #00006d, #123456 and so on. Regarding the **regex flavor**, it should ideally work in **Notepad++**, if that's no option then Python 2.7 is an alternative.

I tried using the backreference operator I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times). So far, my best attempt is

```
#([0-9a-fA-F])\1{3}[^0-9a-fA-F]
```

but I'm having some troubles:

- It seems I should replace `{3}` by `{2}` for matching exactly three repetitions but I don't see why
- I'm clueless as to how to match 6 repetitions as well. I think that `{3,6}` should match 3, 4, 5 or 6 repetitions but how can I exclude 4 and 5 repetitions? I thought about `#([0-9a-fA-F])\1{3}[^0-9a-fA-F]|#([0-9a-fA-F])\1{6}[^0-9a-fA-F]` but there must be a less ugly syntax for that, right?

Comment: this is not what regular expressions are for, you should convert the values to actual numbers and compare the ranges that way.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use thie regex:

```
#([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f])((?=\2)\1|(?:\1\2){2})\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP9uO9/3)

This should work on PCRE or on Python as well.

Comment: Thank you but why should I use {2} and {5} instead of {3} and {6} here? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Matching `{2}` and `{5}` because one match has already been made by first `[0-9a-fA-F]` so total `1+2=3` OR `1+5=6` matches.

Comment: This only matches greys of the form `#AAAAAA` and not greys of the form `#ABABAB`.

Comment: @brentonstrine Well, but it's trivial to change that: `#((([0-9a-fA-F])(?3)?)\2\2)\b`

Comment: @anubhava That's true. In that case we can though trivially replace `?3` by `[0-9a-fA-F]` again. I just hate being unnecessarily redundant ;o)

Comment: @bwoebi: Just realized OP is using Notepad++ so PCRE is fine with that.

Comment: Without using PCRE we can use: `#([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f])((?=\2)\1|(?:\1\2){2})\b`

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for a regex that also supports `gray` and `rgb(...)`:

```
#([0-9A-Fa-f])([0-9A-Fa-f])((?=\2)\1|(?:\1\2){2})\b|gray|rgb\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*\4\s*,\s*\4\s*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3nf288/1

Answer (score -2):

`#([0-Fa-f][0-Fa-f])(\1{2}|\1{5})\b`

Matches `#AAA`, `#AAAAAA` and also `#ABABAB` type grays.

BTW, `[0-Fa-f]` is identical to `[0-9a-fA-F]`.

Edit: I am rong.

Comment: No `[0-Fa-f]` is not identical to `[0-9a-fA-F]` `[0-F]` also matches `:`, `:` etc

Comment: And your regex also allows `#EEEEEEEEEEEE` as valid input.

Comment: Lol whoops. Nice catch there. Er, catches. :D

Comment: Just delete your answer instead of editing in "I am rong [sic!]"

Comment: It's still a helpful answer for some people. It worked in my case since I don't have any #AAAAAAAAAAAA patterns, and it catches grays that the other one doesn't. Despite being "rong" my answer will probably be more helpful to most people in most situations, especially since I've indicated that there are problems with my answer so that people can read the comments and see the details.