# Regex match String with only one type of character

Tags: regex

Trying to find a regex that matches to a String with only one type of character:

Example:  **"aaaaaa"** or **"a"**

What expression would do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

Answer (score 2):

Using capturing group and backreference:

```
/^(.)\1*$/
```

According to the regular expression engine you're using you may need to replace `\1` with `$`.