# Python not recognizing regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using the solution obtained from this question [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

> The regex you need is /(.)\1{9,}/.

https://regex101.com/ is recognizing it, `grep` recognizes it, but python does not.

Ultimately I want to replace the match with a single space, for example:

```
>> text = 'this is text???????????????'
>> pattern = re.compile(r'/(.)\1{5,}/')
>> re.sub(pattern,'\s',text)
'this is text '
```

However, `search`, `findall`, even `match` do not recognize the pattern, any idea as to why?

Comment: [Pythex.org](http://pythex.org/) is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1{9,}', ' ',text)
```

The slashes are not part of the regex, they are a syntactic construct by which some languages form regex literals (and in case of PHP's preg module, an oddity).

With your regexp, you would have matched `this is text/?????????????/`, and transformed it into `this is text\s` (note that `\s` has no meaning in the replacement string).

Comment: The hilarious part is that the second answer to that question contains the correct regex for Python.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Oh haha indeed!

Comment: Even tho it was included, the explanation was great. Thank you.