# Remove Consecutive Repeated Characters with PostgreSQL regexp_replace function

Tags: regex, postgresql

Remove all consecutive repeated characters using Regular Expression.

In Javascript this works well:

```
txt='aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd'.replace(/(?!(?!(.)\1))./g,'');
```

Returns `'a b 8 b c d'`

How can I do it with Posgresql regexp_replace function?
This won't work:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd',E'(?!(?!(.)\\\\1)).','g');

$ psql -c "SELECT regexp_replace('aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd',E'(?!(?!(.)\\1)).','g');"
     regexp_replace      
-------------------------
 aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd
(1 row)

$ psql -c "SELECT regexp_replace('aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd','(?!(?!(.)\1)).','g');"   
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid backreference number
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `select string_agg(x[1],'') from regexp_matches('aaa bbb 888 111122222 1234 bbb ccc ddd','(.)\1*','g') t(x);`

Comment: @Abelisto This returns `a b 8 12 1234 b c d`, which isn't exactly what the OP wanted, but I upvoted your comment because it is close.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is because different input to test some more use cases.

Comment: The OP wants only the first character of every word (contain it numbers or letters), at least that is how I read it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To get the first character of every word (not just delete repeated characters): `select string_agg(x,'') from unnest(array(select regexp_matches('aaa bbb 888 111122222 1234, bbb ccc ddd','\m(\w)\w*(\W*)','g'))) t(x);`

Comment: @Abelisto I just tested this and it didn't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am confused. Just after copy/paste to the psql it does not work. But after delete and reenter `(\W*)‌` part it works fine.

Comment: @Abelisto - You should put this down as an answer. Your first comment perfectly solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times) that can help you to get the answer:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('aaa bbb 888 bbb ccc ddd', '(.)\1{1,}', '\1', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 a b 8 b c d
(1 row)
```

It uses a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to capture the groups of repeating characters.