# Regular expression to ONLY print duplicate letters in string

Tags: regex, sed

The following **sed** snippet will remove the duplicate letters in the string and print only the unique letters :

```
> echo "remove duplicate letters from string" | sed ':;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/;t'
> remov duplicatsfng
```

What would be the regular expression to ONLY print the duplicate letters - thus unique letters are discarded ( eg: v and d ) and the letters appearing more than once should not be repeated in the output !

The result should be :

```
> remo lits
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

Comment: Why not just iterate through the string and count the number of times each character appears?

Comment: @Isaac: That's no duplicate.

Comment: Note that you used more than a regular expression: a substitution and conditional jump.

Comment: @Cyrus I beg to differ, that answer slightly tweaked yields (in javascript) `"aabbacdefgghijklmnoopq".match(/(.)\1{1,}/g) == ["aa", "bb", "gg", "oo"]`

Comment: @Isaac: But it returns `null` for "abcab", even though `a` and `b` are duplicate.

Comment: @choroba good point, i stand corrected

Comment: if you are interested in only the duplicate letters and not the order: `echo "remove duplicate letters from string" | grep -oi '[a-z]' | awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do that with GNU sed:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(.)\1*(.+)\1+/\1\1\2/;ta;s/(((.)\3)*)./\1/g;s/.(.)/\1/g;'
```

details: for the string `"remove duplicate letters from string"`

`:a;s/(.)\1*(.+)\1+/\1\1\2/;ta;` : this part replaces each duplicated letters separated by at least one character with two consecutive letters. Result:

```
rreemmoov  duplliicattssfng
```

`s/(((.)\3)*)./\1/g;` this one removes letters that stay alone. Result:

```
rreemmoo  lliittss
```

`s/.(.)/\1/g` this one removes consecutive letters. Result:

```
remo lits
```

---

With perl:

In a more or less similar way you can write something like this:

```
perl -pe's/(.)(?!.*\1)//g;while(s/(.)(.*)\1+/\1\2/g){}'
```

It's shorter but it's probably more efficient to use this second version with the autosplit switch and a hash to count the number of occurrences for each characters:

```
perl -F -ane'$h{$_}++ for(@F);for(@F){if($h{$_}>1){$h{$_}=1;print}}'
```

Comment: Impressive. It only works with GNU Sed, unfortunately; BSD Sed, with _extended_ regexes (`-E`), doesn't support back-references such as `\1` (in the regex itself, as opposed to in the replacement string).

Comment: @mklement0: The OP seems to use GNU sed, but you can do the same with perl: `perl -pe's/(.)(?!.*\1)//g;while(s/(.)(.*)\1+/\1\2/g){}'`

Comment: @mklement0: I will wait a little before adding the perl one liner, because I don't have the confirmation that this is what the OP wants, and I think there's probably smarter or more efficient ways to do it with perl.

Comment: Wow, I am impressed by the above original solution - although it looks over-engineered ! 
The result is correct ... I will edit the question to clarify further the fact that only letters appearing more than once are needed !
Perl solution is welcomed too !

Comment: The last perl snippet using the hash can be rewritten as 'perl -F -e '$h{$_}++ for (@F); for(keys %h){print if $h{$_} > 1 }' to avoid that '$h{$_}=1'

Comment: @AdrianS.: if order doesn't matter, you can indeed write that, you can even shorten it to `perl -F -ane'$h{$_}++for@F;--$h{$_}&&print for keys%h'`

Comment: @AdrianS.: or `perl -F -anE'$h{$_}++for@F;say grep{$h{$_}>1}keys %h'` or `perl -nE'/(.)(?=.*\1)(??{$h{$1}=1})/;say keys%h'`

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any awk on any system:

```
$ echo "remove duplicate letters from string" |
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=length($0);) { chr=substr($0,i,1); if (gsub(chr,"") > 1) printf "%c", chr } print "" }'
remo lits
```

Answer (score 1):

with posix sed (and gnu)

```
echo "remove duplicate letters from string" | sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\(.\).*\2.*\)\2/\1/;ta' -e "G;:b" -e '/^\(.\)\(.*\)\1\(.*\n.*\)/s//\1\2\3\1/;tb' -e 's/.//;/^\n/b e' -e 'b b' -e ':e' -e 's/.//'
```

concept

- limit occurence of letter to maximum twice `':a' -e 's/\(\(.\).*\2.*\)\2/\1/;ta'`
- add a newline (at the end) using holder buffer `G`
- test if first char is there twice (before a second line), if yes put it in a second line and remove the second occurence of the letter `:b" -e '/^\(.\)\(.*\)\1\(.*\n.*\)/s//\1\2\3\1/;tb`
- remove first char `s/.//`
- if first char is newline, go to end of script, remove the newline (and print) `/^\n/b e'` ... `-e ':e'`
- if not loop `-e 'b b'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/\n*(([^\n]).*)\2/\n\1/;ta;s/\n(.)[^\n]*/\1/g' file
```

While removing duplicate characters prefix those concerned, with a unique marker i.e `\n`. Then remove all characters not associated with a marker ( and markers too) to leave only those characters which had duplicates.

Comment: I really like this one, it seems very logical !