# Regular expression with groups?

Tags: .net, regex

In .NET, I'm trying to parse strings like these into groups of numbers. The "a" and "b" are optional (but fixed) letters:

```
111a222b333   --> groups: num1=111, num2=222, num3=333
111           --> groups: num1=111
111b333       --> groups: num1=111, num3=333
b333          --> groups: num3=333
```

The regular expressions I've tried include:

```
(?<num1>\d+)?a?(?<num2>\d+)?b?(?<num3>\d+)?
(?<num1>\d+)*.*(a(?<num2>\d+))*.*(b(?<num3>\d+))*
```

But they are not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first regex begins with a superfluous '('.

Comment: "they are not working" - in what way are they not working? Are they giving you errors? are they not matching anything? are they returning the wrong things? Be more specific in what problems you've had. Providing standalone copy and paste runable code in a minimal complete verifiable example helps a lot (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The second one never reaches group two and three because of the dot with asterisk being greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need combine the `?` (zero or one of) so to speak in a group (not a capture group).

Thus turning this:

```
a?(?<num2>\d+)
```

Into:

```
(?:a(?<num2>\d+))?
```

The full regex would then be:

```
(?<num1>\d+)?(?:a(?<num2>\d+))?(?:b(?<num3>\d+))?
```

Here's a [**live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/3zuEo5/3).

As you can see it correctly yields:

[image]

Comment: I've discovered that the first number is optional. I've updated the question. This answer no longer works.

Comment: @GlenLittle I've updated the answer to accommodate for your edit. This includes the live preview.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<num1>\d*)?a?(?<num2>\d*)?b?(?<num3>\d*)
```

You were close, just needed to cover the case when the digit isn't there.

[Preview](https://regex101.com/r/mv7rLs/1)

Answer (score -1):

This is a similar post: [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

`/([0-9])\1*/` should match what you're looking for, since in .NET, quantifiers are greedy by default.

Comment: What question are you answering?