# Remove strings with repeating characters [Python]

Tags: python, regex

I need to determine if a string is composed of a certain repeating character, for example `eeeee`, `55555`, or `!!!`.

I know this regex `'e{1,15}'` can match `eeeee` but it obviously can't match `555`. I tried `[a-z0-9]{1-15}` but it matches even the strings I don't need like `Hello`.

The solution doesn't have to be regex. I just can't think of any other way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times). You can easily adapt the regex from the accepted anser to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string consists of a single repeating character if and only if all characters in it are the same. You can easily test that by constructing a set out of the string: `set('55555')`.

All characters are the same if and only if the set has size 1:

```
>>> len(set('55555')) == 1
True
>>> len(set('Hello')) == 1
False
>>> len(set('')) == 1
False
```

If you want to allow the empty string as well (set size 0), then use `<= 1` instead of `== 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex solution (via `re.search()` function):

```
import re

s = 'eeeee'
print(bool(re.search(r'^(.)\1+$', s)))   # True

s = 'ee44e'
print(bool(re.search(r'^(.)\1+$', s)))   # False
```

---

`^(.)\1+$` :

- `(.)` - capture any character
- `\1+` - backreference to the previously captured group, repeated one or many times

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use regex for this, a test to determine if all characters in the string are the same will produce the desired output:

```
s = "eee"
assert len(s) > 0
reference = s[0]
result = all([c==reference for c in s])
```

Or use `set` as Thomas showed, which is probably a better way.