# How to count if there is a string of 3 or more chars in a string bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a password check script and I would like to be able to check if password includes a string of 3 or more of the same characters (aaa, babbb, asj111) all would be a "bad password".  I have tried 
`grep -E '(.)\1{2,}' $password` 
but I want this in an if statement to then do something if I find more than 3 characters.  All help is appreciated!

Comment: Usually passwords are stored in hashed form. Why do you think the hash will be "better" if you do not have same characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

Comment: @AlexM it's not a duplicate; the question here is about how to combine `grep` and an `if` statement, not about the regex (the OP got that point right).

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes this is a simple project I am doing to become familiar with shell scripting and learning the basics for it and understanding how  it works

Comment: @JadeFisher, OK. But when write scripts always have security in mind

Comment: `3ksad9jdsaaa9324jk` is probably a much better password than `aabbcc`. Encourage your users to use longer passwords instead of nitpicking about arbitrary restrictions on shorter ones.

Comment: @chepner I have no users this is for me to understand shell coding...

Answer (score 3):

Use the return code of `grep`:

```
if grep -q '\(.\)\1\1' <<< "$password"; then
    echo "Bad password!"
    # Do something, like exit 1
fi
```

The `-q` option is to keep `grep` quiet. I didn't use the `-E` (extended) option, use it if you want.

Comment: Would you be able to adapt this to make it any 3 lowercase letters or any 3 uppercase letters?

Comment: @JadeFisher: you mean three consecutive lowercase or three consecutive uppercase? Like `thisIsBad` and `THISiSbAd` but `ThIsISgoOd`?

Comment: @JadeFisher You could use `grep -q '\([[:lower:]]\{3\}\|[[:upper:]]\{3\}\)'`

Answer (score 1):

Put your pattern in a variable. It matches any character, then the same character twice again (so three times in total).

```
pattern='(.)\1{2}'
```

Then test it with the bash regex comparison operator `=~`

```
[[ $password =~ $pattern ]] && echo "bad password"
```