# Finding a sequence of characters in string

Tags: python, string, character, string-length

Using python, I am trying to find any sequence of characters in a string by specifying the length of this chain of characters.

For Example, if we have the following variable, I want to extract any identical sequence of characters with a length of 5:

```
x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh111ljhjkh1111"
```

the result should be:

```
11111
11111
```

how can I do that?

Comment: `Counter` could be your friend.

Comment: You should use regex to match a repeated expression. This post should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660739/7692562

Comment: @user5173426, can you elaborate? `Counter` by itself doesn't tell you anything about consecutive runs of identical characters.

Comment: This is not a do-your-homework-for-you site and neither it is tutorial site for people who don't know any programming at all. To ensure an answer please show what you have tried yourself so far.

Comment: @user5173426 `Counter` is not useful here because the characters have to be adjacent, `itertools.groupby` could be used though

Comment: @jdehesa Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @user5173426 I think I misunderstood the OP, I think they mean "identify sequences of `n` identical characters, no "identify identical `n`-long sequences within the string".

Comment: Better get my coffee.

Answer (score 3):

`itertools` to the rescue :)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> val = 5
>>> x
'jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh111ljhjkh1111'
>>> [y[0]*val for y in itertools.groupby(x) if len(list(y[1])) == val]
['11111', '11111']
```

Edit: naming well

```
>>> [char*val for char,grouper in itertools.groupby(x) if len(list(grouper)) == val]
['11111', '11111']
```

Or the more memory efficient oneliner suggested by @Chris_Rands

```
>>> [k*val for k, g in itertools.groupby(x) if sum(1 for _ in g) == val]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are fine with using regex, makes your code a lot cleaner:

```
[row[0] for row in re.findall(r'((.)\2{4,})', s)]
```

[regex101 - example](https://regex101.com/r/XCyaJw/3)

Comment: This pattern does indeed match the sequence that OP is looking for. But `search` only finds the first instance. Is it possible to find _all_ instances?

Comment: @hansolo, that works for the OP's sample input, but I think that he also wants sequences that don't contain the character "1". For example, `"22222 foo QQQQQ"` should return `["22222", "QQQQQ"]`

Comment: @Kevin Then something like `', '.join(y*5 for y in  re.findall(r'(.)\1{4}', x))`

Comment: Looking good, now :-) I was hoping there would be a findall-based solution that captures only and exactly the full sequences, so that no list comp would be required. But I don't think you can match the sequence without capturing the first character by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The original answer (below) is for a different problem (identifying repeated patterns of `n` characters in the string). Here is one possible one liner to solve the problem:

```
x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh111ljhjkh1111"
n = 5
res = [x[i:i + n] for i, c in enumerate(x) if x[i:i + n] == c * n]
print(res)
# ['11111', '11111']
```

---

**Original (wrong) answer**

Using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh111ljhjkh1111"
n = 5
c = Counter(x[i:i + n] for i in range(len(x) - n + 1))
for k, v in c.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(*([k] * v), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
**111
**111
*1111
*1111
11111
11111
1111*
1111*
111**
111**
```

Comment: although its for a different problem, I liked this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Very ugly solution :-)

```
x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh22222jhjkh1111"
for c, i in enumerate(x):
    if i == x[c+1:c+2] and i == x[c+2:c+3] and i == x[c+3:c+4] and i == x[c+4:c+5]:
        print(x[c:c+5])
```

Comment: Style tip: consider using `for c, i in enumerate(x):` instead of manually incrementing a count variable.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code. Still ugly, but should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**11111**klhhkjh111ljhjkh1111"

seq_length = 5

for item in set(x):
    if seq_length*item in x:
        for i in range(x.count(seq_length*item)):
            print(seq_length*item)
```

it works by leveraging `set()` to easily construct the sequence you're looking for and then searches for it in the text

outputs your desired output:

```
11111
11111
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's change a little your source string:

```
x = "jhg**11111**jjhgj**22222**klhhkjh33333jhjkh44444"
```

The regex should be:

```
pat = r'(.)\1{4}'
```

Here you have a capturing group (a single char) and a backreference
to it (4 times), so totally the same char must occur 5 times.

One variant to print the result, although less intuitive is:

```
res = re.findall(pat, x)
print(res)
```

But the above code prints:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

i.e. a list, where each position is **only the capturing group** (in our case
the **first** char), not the whole match.

So I propose also the second variant, with `finditer` and
printing both start position and the **whole** match:

```
for match in re.finditer(pat, x):
    print('{:2d}: {}'.format(match.start(), match.group()))
```

For the above data the result is:

```
 5: 11111
19: 22222
33: 33333
43: 44444
```