# How to check whether or not a string consists of a single repeating digit using Python

Tags: python, duplicates, digits, leading-zero

the code:

def repeatingDigits(digits):
pattern = set(digits.lstrip("0"))
print(pattern)

```
if len(pattern) > 1:
    return(False)

if len(pattern) == 1:
  return(True)
```

repeatingDigits("0111")
''TRUE''
repeatingDigits("0112")
''FALSE''

Comment: `len(set(digits.lstrip("0"))) == 1` is easier than doing this with a regex IMO.

Comment: @Sara Is this an exercise for learning regular expressions?

Comment: This should answer your question: [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times) You only need to combine this with a regex for "zero or more times the digit 0" which should be easy to find.

Comment: This seems to be a task assignment. 

look at regular expression: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
in particular at:
`0*` for loading zeroes
at `\d` fr digits
at `$` for end of iline
at '(' and ')' for grouping, for back references (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#checking-for-a-pair )

Comment: I can solve this problem in a different way, but my problem is that I don't know how to write it down whit the mentioned code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex: `^0*([1-9])\1*$`

Explanation:

- `^`   : begin searching at start of string
- `0*`  : search for any repeated 0's
- `([1-9])`: match digits other than 0 and remember it
- `\1*`  :  match one or more instances of the previously matched digit
- `$`  : end of string

The anchor tokens ^ and $ allow weeding out multiple occurrence of recurring digits.
Python code:

```
import re
def repeatingDigits(digits):
    pattern = r"^0*([1-9])\1*$"
    return re.search(pattern, digits)
```

Comment: Great! I have made a change to it:      ^0*(([1-9]))\1*$

Comment: @Sara - great! I see you are new to SO. Consider marking an answer as accepted if it helped you. It's not obligatory though.

Comment: yes I am new and I did not know about marking the best answer. Thanks for the explanation. Best,