# Detect if there are 7 or more of the same symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I need to know if in a string which contains only '1's and '0's has 7 of one of those in a row. My first thought was to iterate through the string like so:

```py
for i in inp:
    if count == 6:
        answ = True
    this = i
    if this == other:
        count+=1
        other = this
    else:
        other = this
        count = 0
```

But it randomly gives out a wrong answer. My next idea was to use regex `(.)\1{7,}` like this:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1{7,}')
found = re.search(pattern, inp)
if found != None:
    answ = True
```

But it still sometimes makes mistakes. Anyone has any ideas on why that would happen?
Regex was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

Comment: Your regular expression checks for *8* or more occurrence of a value: `(.)` is the first one, `\1{7,}` checks for 7 more.

Comment: A counter-based approach is natural and, when properly debugged, won't fail randomly. You just need to think about the logic a bit more.

Comment: Until you can prove it's a bottleneck, I wouldn't do anything more complicated than `'1111111' in inp or '0000000' in inp`.

Answer (score 3):

[cheper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s comment actually worked flawlessly. I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner

> Until you can prove it's a bottleneck, I wouldn't do anything more complicated than `'1111111' in inp or '0000000' in inp`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there is a regex pattern that could work for this, but like many other programmers, I've never quite figured out how regex works. However, the following script should be able to determine if there is a substring that matches your description.

```py
current = None
current_len = 0
answer = False

for i in inp:
    if i == current:
        current_len += 1
        if current_len >= 7:
            answer = True
            break
    else:
        current = i
        current_len = 1

print(answer)
```

Obviously, the answer variable in this case would be `True` if there are 7 consecutive characters and `False` if there aren't. Hopefully this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you follow this approach?

```
def check_line(l, target = 7):
     return l if any(map(lambda y: any(map(lambda x:len(x) == target, l.split(y))), ["1","0"])) else ""
    
print(check_line("00000001111"))
print(check_line("000000001111"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
00000001111
```

This solution works if you want sequences of **exactly** 7 elements: if you need 7 or more, chepner approach is the cleanest.

Comment: @JonSG - oh, he needs consecutive -  well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I like @chepner's comment and I might start with that as echoed by @ive. Since you started a regex based answer, you might also try:

```
import re

def check_line(line):
    return re.search(r"0{7,}|1{7,}", line) is not None

tests = [
    "00001111",
    "00000001",
    "01111111",
    "100000001111",
    "10000100001111"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, check_line(test))
```

That should give you:

```
00001111 False
00000001 True
01111111 True
100000001111 True
10000100001111 False
```